# Developing a simple website from scratch using https://css-tricks.com/app-from-scratch-1-design/

Tags: html

I am following all the steps from beginning. In chapter four there are codes displayed.. I am not getting where to paste those codes in my local pc.. that is in xamp...can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

**If you are on mac**

1. Copy all your files & paste them into the `Applications > XAMPP > htdocs` (root folder).
2. Then Navigate to `localhost/index.php`

---

**If you are on windows**

1. Copy all your files & paste them into the `c:\xampp\htdocs` (root folder).
2. Then Navigate to `localhost/index.php` from the browser

---

Note : Before you navigate to the `localhost/index.php` you have to **start** the Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concentrate on setting up a localhost. BTW, there is a very easy way to set it up if you are using php: [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

So, name your first file to be called as index.php or index.html, and do
`php -S localhost:8000` in console from the same directory. After that it should propose you to go to the browser and see your content at http://localhost:8000/